# Arrays multiplication

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

How to write arrayt multiplication (multiplicating two matrieces ie 3x3) of arrays of known size in c++ ? What will be the difference using pointers and reference ?

Comment: Define "array multiplication"...

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Could you post some code that maybe doesn't work so we can help you?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) which is a multi-dimentional array and implementing your own multiplication logic or perhaps [Boost.BasicLinearAlgebra](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) which has Matrix types in it?  These libraries will do most if not all of the work you need to do.